# Are mixed case like IaC or GoF in acronyms normative or allowed?

Tags: capitalization, acronyms

In IT (Information Technology) there are a lot of acronyms with mixed case:

- GoF: Gang of four, the oldest I found.
- IaC: Infrastructure as Code, very common nowadays

I understand the logic behing using a lowercase for "as","of" etc.
But since the oldest one I remember is "GoF" from the 90' I wonder if it was regular english or just an IT engineer habit:

- Is it correct english?
- When did it appear?
- Is it specific to technological acronyms?

I did my research about acronyms and initials case, but no article are very specific when the case are mixed.

This is related but only about acronyms which became regular words:
[When does an acronym lose its capitalization, e.g. RaDAR 'radar'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6064/when-does-an-acronym-lose-its-capitalization-e-g-radar-radar)
It's about LiDAR and RaDAR but I didn't find other reference on it's usage with this specific writting.

Comment: For the final part of this, there are existing questions about whether to capitalise acronyms such as [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/595684/capitalization-of-acronyms-maybe-there-is-no-definite-correctness-for-all-case/595691). [This question asks about Nato/NATO](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51924/proper-capitalization-of-commonly-used-acronyms-and-initialisms); someone asked [a similar question about NASA/Nasa](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/488580/conversion-of-all-cap-acronyms-to-first-letter-only-when-did-nasa-become-nasa) which was closed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capitalizing prepositions in abbreviations?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/507902/capitalizing-prepositions-in-abbreviations)

Comment: There's also [a question about COVID/CoViD](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/528487/is-it-covid-or-covid-covid-how-should-the-word-be-spelled/531799#531799) which discusses DDoS, and [another about pascal case abbreviations that was closed as opinion-based](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/483299/should-devops-be-in-pascal-case/483305#483305).

Comment: @StuartF Yes thanks, that the same question.... with 2 opposite answers.

Answer (score 2):

It's true there aren't that many mixed-case acronyms outside the world of IT. And more often than not, articles and prepositions are omitted entirely: **USA** instead of tUSoA, and **OBE** in place of OotBE (Order of the British Empire).

One that does appear occasionally is **DoD** which is *the Department of Defense*,  and **WoW** (World of Warcraft). Sometimes I see *Lord of the Rings* shortened to **LotR** but with the exception of DoD, and other government roles, titles, and departments, there is no hard-and-fast rule to using uppercase or lowercase for acronyms. For example, **faqs** or **FAQS**; **asap** or **ASAP** (as fast as possible) are commonly used.